# Error in executing a python script at remote machine through subprocess

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I am trying to execute a python script through `subprocess`. First I tried to execute the python script present on my local machine through following code:

```
str = 'abc'
sub_result = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,"./script.py"] + str)
```

this worked correctly. Now I am trying to execute the script present on remote machine through `subprocess`. First I couldn't find any example on how to do it through `subprocess.Popen()` like I did for local machine. I then tried to use `subprocess.call()` in the following code but I am having issues with it:

```
str = 'abc'
sub_result = subprocess.call('ssh username@hostname python ./script.py' + str)
```

I get following error:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What is the mistake I am doing and also how can I mention the `password` in the `ssh` command for connection?

**UPDATE:** Based on @musiphil's answer I modified my code and no I am using:

```
str = 'abc'
sub_result = subprocess.call(['ssh', 'username@hostname', 'python', './script.py'] + str)
```

But I get this error:

```
    ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied, please try again.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

Comment: The code you're running should raise a TypeError (can only concatenate list (not "str") to list) before you run into SSH issues.

Comment: @jd. I have kept `str` as list. I forgot to update the str in above code

Comment: @jd. I have modified the code in update part above

Comment: `['a']+'b'` raises TypeError in Python.

Comment: keep one issue per question. There are two issues: incorrect `subprocess` usage and how to authenticate via `ssh`. @musiphil answered the former. Ask a separate question for the latter.

Comment: related: [OSError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory while using python subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18962785/4279)

Answer (score 3):

You should give an argv-style list, unless you also specify `shell=True`:

```
str = 'abc'
sub_result = subprocess.call(
    ['ssh', 'username@hostname', 'python', './script.py', str])
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call.

Comment: and how can I mention the password with ssh?

Comment: I got following error when I tried to execute your above code : `ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.`

Comment: Can you connect to the remote host by running SSH manually? In any case the subprocess approach is going to be tedious to get working. You could try `paramiko` which implements the SSH protocol in Python.

Comment: @jd. How can I mention the password with ssh?

Comment: You didn't answer my previous question. Before sending a password you need to authenticate the remote host (this uses your known_hosts file). Then passing the password is going to be quite complex, check the SSH client documentation. I mentionned `paramiko`, this is going to be way easier to use than the SSH command-line client.

Comment: @jd. I have to use `subprocess` as it is the requirement of system and also for uniformity across application.

Comment: @jd. I am able to ssh to the server directly from terminal

Answer (score 1):

You can mention password on ssh with the help of [sshpass](https://gist.github.com/arunoda/7790979) command.

```
    ['sshpass', '-p', 'password', 'ssh','username@%s' % address]
```