# subprocess.Popen() error (No such file or directory) when calling command with arguments as a string

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am trying to count the number of lines in a file using Python functions. Within the current directory, while `os.system("ls")` finds the file, the command `subprocess.Popen(["wc -l filename"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE`) does not work.

Here is my code:

```
>>> import os
>>> import subprocess
>>> os.system("ls")
sorted_list.dat
0
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(["wc -l sorted_list.dat"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/a200/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
File "/Users/a200/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You should pass the arguments as a list (recommended):

```
subprocess.Popen(["wc", "-l", "sorted_list.dat"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Otherwise, you need to pass `shell=True` if you want to use the whole `"wc -l sorted_list.dat"` string as a command (not recommended, can be a security hazard).

```
subprocess.Popen("wc -l sorted_list.dat", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Read more about `shell=True` security issues [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

In this case, to use the command as a whole string and avoid the security issues of `shell=True` you can use [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html)

```py
import subprocess
import shlex

command = "wc -l sorted_list.dat"
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: I am getting error : "python3: can't open file '$SDE/install/lib/python3.6/site-packages/p4testutils/bf_switchd_dev_status.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory" even if shell=True. The same script runs properly on shell but gives error when called by subprocess. What may be the issue?

Comment: @Nagmat Is `$SDE` an env var or really the folder name? I think you may have to expand the value of `$SDE` in your python string first?

Comment: it is an environmental variable. I resolved the issue by writing the long path.

Answer (score 6):

The error occurs because you are trying to run a command named `wc -l sorted_list.dat`, that is, it is trying to find a *file* named like `"/usr/bin/wc -l sorted dat"`.

Split your arguments:

```
["wc", "-l", "sorted_list.dat"]
```