# Why can't the Python command "subprocess.Popen" find the jar file to run?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jar, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to run code from this repo: https://github.com/tylin/coco-caption, specifically from https://github.com/tylin/coco-caption/blob/master/pycocoevalcap/tokenizer/ptbtokenizer.py, line 51-52:

```
p_tokenizer = subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd=path_to_jar_dirname, \
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The error I get running this is

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I can't figure out why the file can't be found.

The jar I'm trying to run is:

```
stanford-corenlp-3.4.1.jar
```

You can see the structure of directory by going to https://github.com/tylin/coco-caption/tree/master/pycocoevalcap/tokenizer. For more specificity into what my actual arguments are when I run the line of code:

```
cmd= ['java', '-cp', 'stanford-corenlp-3.4.1.jar', 'edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer', '-preserveLines', '-lowerCase', 'tmpWS5p0Z'],
```

and

```
path_to_dirname =abs_path_to_folder/tokenizer
```

I can see the jar that needs to be run, and it looks to be in the right place, so why can't python find it. (Note: I'm using python2.7.) And the temporary File 'tmpWS5p0Z' is where it should be.

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try an *absolute* path  ( meaning the path beginning from root `/` )

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths

for relative paths in python see i.e. [Relative paths in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python) , [How to refer to relative paths of resources when working with a code repository in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270951/how-to-refer-to-relative-paths-of-resources-when-working-with-a-code-repository)

UPDATE:

As a test try `subprocess.Popen()` with the `shell=True` option and give an absolute path for any involved file, including `tmpWS5p0Z`

in this `subprocess.Popen()` call are involved two paths :

1) the python path, python has to find the `java` executable and the `stanford-corenlp-3.4.1.jar` which is essentially a java program with its own path

2) the java path of `stanford-corenlp-3.4.1.jar`

as this is all too complicated try

`p_tokenizer = subprocess.Popen(['/absolute_path_to/java -cp /absolute_path_to/stanford-corenlp-3.4.1.jar /absolute_path_to/edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer -preserveLines -lowerCase /absolute_path_to/tmpWS5p0Z' ], shell=True)`

[Python specify popen working directory via argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685157/python-specify-popen-working-directory-via-argument)

[Python subprocess.Popen() error (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010939/python-subprocess-popen-error-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: I've updated my question, but my path_to_dirname is already on the absolute path. Updated question to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped. Basically, the problem was that I assumed the computer I'm using had java installed. It did not.

Comment: root is `/`, not `\\`

Comment: Where was your temporary file?

Comment: `shell=True` was the missing part for me, the relative paths did not seem to resolve without it.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case it might help someone:

I was struggling with the same problem (same https://github.com/tylin/coco-caption code). Might be relevant to say that I was running the code with python 3.7 on CentOS using `qsub`. So I changed

```
cmd = ['java', '-cp', 'stanford-corenlp-3.4.1.jar', 'edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer', '-preserveLines', '-lowerCase', 'tmpWS5p0Z']
```

to

```
cmd = ['/abs/path/to/java -cp /abs/path/to/stanford-corenlp-3.4.1.jar edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer -preserveLines -lowerCase ', ' /abs/path/to/temporary_file']
```

Using absolute paths fixed the `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Notice that I still put `'/abs/path/to/temporary_file'` as second element in the `cmd` list, because it got added later on. But then something went wrong in the tokenizer java subprocess, I don't know why or what, just observing because:

```
p_tokenizer = subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd=path_to_jar_dirname, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
token_lines = p_tokenizer.communicate(input=sentences.rstrip())[0]
```

Here `token_lines` was an empty list (which is not the wanted behavior). Executing this in IPython resulted in the following (just the `subprocess.Popen(...`, not the `communicate`).

```
Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
    at edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer.getNext(PTBTokenizer.java:278)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer.getNext(PTBTokenizer.java:163)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.process.AbstractTokenizer.hasNext(AbstractTokenizer.java:55)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer.tokReader(PTBTokenizer.java:444)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer.tok(PTBTokenizer.java:416)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer.main(PTBTokenizer.java:760)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:279)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:290)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:185)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:210)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:287)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBLexer.zzRefill(PTBLexer.java:24511)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBLexer.next(PTBLexer.java:24718)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer.getNext(PTBTokenizer.java:276)
    ... 5 more
```

Again, I don't know why or what, but I just wanted to share that doing this fixed it:

```
cmd = ['/abs/path/to/java -cp /abs/path/to/stanford-corenlp-3.4.1.jar edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer -preserveLines -lowerCase /abs/path/to/temporary_file']
```

And changing `cmd.append(os.path.join(path_to_jar_dirname, os.path.basename(tmp_file.name)))` into `cmd[0] += os.path.join(path_to_jar_dirname, os.path.basename(tmp_file.name))`.

So making `cmd` into a list with only 1 element, containing the entire command with absolute paths at once. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where was your temporary file?

Comment: In the same directory as the stanford-corenlp-3.4.1.jar :) so in coco-caption/pycocoevalcap/tokenizer/

Answer (score 0):

As @Lars mentioned above the issue I had was that I Java wasn't installed. Solved it with:

```
sudo apt update    
sudo apt install default-jdk
sudo apt install default-jre
```

Making this post since I had this issue twice (due to reinstallation problems) and forgot about it.