# Reading terminal output in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to open zip in terminal in python using subprocess, but I'm getting an error.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

my purpose is to see if the process is successful or unsuccessful after opening the zip file and to print it.

Also my code:

```
from subprocess import run
output = run("unzip -P password /Users/username/Desktop/something.zip -d /Users/Desktop/Desktop/something", capture_output=True).stdout
print(output)
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python subprocess.Popen() error (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010939/python-subprocess-popen-error-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
output = run("unzip -P password /Users/username/Desktop/something.zip -d /Users/Desktop/Desktop/something", capture_output=True).stdout
```

to

```
output = run(["unzip", "-P", "password", "/Users/username/Desktop/something.zip", "-d", "/Users/Desktop/Desktop/something"], capture_output=True).stdout
```