# Python Subprocess Call with variables

Tags: python, subprocess, python-2.6

I am currently writing a script for a customer.

This script reads from a config file.
Some of these infos are then stores in variables.

Afterwards I want to use subprocess.call to execute a mount command
So I am using these variables to build the mount command

```
call("mount -t cifs //%s/%s %s -o username=%s" % (shareServer, cifsShare, mountPoint, shareUser))
```

However this does not work

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mount_execute.py", line 50, in <module>
    main()
  File "mount_execute.py", line 47, in main
    call("mount -t cifs //%s/%s %s -o username=%s" % (shareServer, cifsShare, mountPoint, shareUser))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 470, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _execute_child
   raise child_exception
 OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

buidling the command first with

```
mountCommand = 'mount -t cifs //%s/%s %s -o username=%s' % (shareServer, cifsShare, mountPoint, shareUser)
call(mountCommand)
```

also results in the same error.

Comment: `call(['mount', '-t', 'cifs', '//%s/%s' % (shareServer, cifsShare), mountPoint, '-o', 'username=%s' % shareUser])`

Comment: The linked question has an answer that technically works, but is unsafe and should not be used.  Consequently, I do not feel it appropriate to mark this question as a duplicate on the grounds that the other was already answered.  Charles Duffy's answer below is much better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your current invocation is written for use with `shell=True`, but doesn't actually use it. If you **really** want to use a string that needs to be parsed with a shell, use `call(yourCommandString, shell=True)`.

---

The better approach is to pass an explicit argument list -- using `shell=True` makes the command-line parsing dependent on the details of the data, whereas passing an explicit list means you're making the parsing decisions yourself (which you, as a human who understands the command you're running, are better-suited to do).

```
call(['mount',
      '-t', 'cifs',
      '//%s/%s' % (shareServer, cifsShare),
      mountPoint,
      '-o', 'username=%s' % shareUser])
```