# Parameter "--outdir" is not recognised via pythons subprocess.call but does work in terminal

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, libreoffice, soffice

I would like to write a python script to automate the conversion of libreoffice ott templates to normal odt files.
if I go to the terminal (bash shell) and I type:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to odt "/path/template.ott" --outdir '/targetpath/template.odt'
```

The output is as expected, an odt file in a new target location.

When I script it (like so:

```
oldfile
outdir = pipes.quote(/targetpath/template.odt)
subprocess.call(['soffice --headless --convert-to odt /path/template.ott --outdir /pathtarget/template.odt'])
```

the output gives me

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

When I try to make the call like this:

```
subprocess.call(["soffice", "--headless", "--convert-to", "odt", pipes.quote(oldpath),outdir])
```

The result is the helptext of soffice, with the the reason:

```
    LibreOffice 4.2.8.2 420m0(Build:2)

    Unknown option: --outdir /targetpath/template.odt
...
```

Comment: Have you tried adding shell=True to the subprocess call?

Comment: Indeed, for passing the command as one string, adding shell=True is a solution! thanks alot. It was indeed an allready answered question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962785/oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-while-using-python-subprocess-in-dj). However, I still cannot get it to work with the list, Again, indeed that bug was mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109665/subprocess-call-using-string-vs-using-list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not try with os.system ?

```
os.system('soffice --headless --convert-to odt "/path/template.ott" --outdir "/targetpath/template.odt"')
```

Comment: Because the `subprocess` module is meant to replace older functions such as `os.system()`.

Comment: indeed. os.system does work, but subprocess should replace that function.