# Converting all images in a folder to .webp using python script

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, webp

I've been working on images for a website and find out that `.webp` format is much more compact than `.jpeg` or `.png` find more on [Docs](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/).

Now I have a folder with almost 25 images & I want to convert all into `.webp` format. Can anyone suggest me how to convert all by using just a python script without using online tools.

Answer (score 4):

Well first of all you have to download the cwebp compressor tool according to your machine(Windows|Linux) from [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download).

Now after extracting the folder in `C:\Program Files\` you have to [set path](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) to `cwebp.exe`, below is my path
`Path:: C:\Program Files\libwebp\bin`

Open cmd to check if you have done right till now.

- `cmd> cwebp -version`

[image: cwebp- version]

- `cmd> python --version`

[image: python --version]

Now it's super easy just run the below script and you have your desired output or you can download my repo on github from [here](https://github.com/PAPERPANKS/cwebp_compressor)

```
# --cwebp_compressor.py--

# cmd> python cwebp_compressor.py folder-name 80

import sys
from subprocess import call
from glob import glob

#folder-name
path = sys.argv[1]
#quality of produced .webp images [0-100]
quality = sys.argv[2]

if int(quality) < 0 or int(quality) > 100:
    print("image quality out of range[0-100] ;/:/")
    sys.exit(0)

img_list = []
for img_name in glob(path+'/*'):
    # one can use more image types(bmp,tiff,gif)
    if img_name.endswith(".jpg") or img_name.endswith(".png") or img_name.endswith(".jpeg"):
        # extract images name(image_name.[jpg|png]) from the full path
        img_list.append(img_name.split('\\')[-1])


# print(img_list)   # for debug
for img_name in img_list:
    # though the chances are very less but be very careful when modifying the below code
    cmd='cwebp \"'+path+'/'+img_name+'\" -q '+quality+' -o \"'+path+'/'+(img_name.split('.')[0])+'.webp\"'
    # running the above command
    call(cmd, shell=False)  
    # print(cmd)    # for debug
```

Comment: Why not run it with both -near_lossless 80 and the lossy, and then take the smaller?

Comment: @JyrkiAlakuijala well when I started with webp conversion I found it tidious to convert all 25 images one-by-one one.....the above code is more on conversion for batch images....well you can do this in your code...nice idea

Comment: I had to change `call(cmd, shell=False)` to `call(cmd, shell=True)` because we are passing a shell command. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18962815/3578289).

Comment: Thanks! I modified it to my needs (use with shell, save files in separate folder). Works well!  My version: https://gist.github.com/apiwonska/d2a0938fc68909e14f83876e72a55325

Answer (score 0):

Old post but I wanted to share my updated version that asks to select a folder, works recursively in this folder and subfolders, asks your for the desired quality and tells you how many images have been converted.

First steps stays the same you need cwebp and python

```
# --cwebp_compressor.py--

import sys
from subprocess import call
from glob import glob
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
from tqdm import tqdm

# open a prompt to select the folder
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
path = filedialog.askdirectory()

# open a prompt to enter the desired quality
quality = input("Enter the desired quality (0-100): ")

if int(quality) < 0 or int(quality) > 100:
    print("Image quality out of range [0-100] ;/:/")
    sys.exit(0)

img_list = []
jpg_count = 0
png_count = 0
jpeg_count = 0
bmp_count = 0
tiff_count = 0
for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for img_name in filenames:
        # one can use more image types(bmp,tiff,gif)
        if img_name.endswith(".jpg"):
            jpg_count += 1
        elif img_name.endswith(".png"):
            png_count += 1
        elif img_name.endswith(".jpeg"):
            jpeg_count += 1
        elif img_name.endswith(".bmp"):
            bmp_count += 1
        elif img_name.endswith(".tiff") or img_name.endswith(".tif"):
            tiff_count += 1
        else:
            continue
        # extract images name(image_name.[jpg|png]) from the full path
        img_list.append(os.path.join(dirpath, img_name))

with tqdm(total=len(img_list), desc="Compressing Images") as pbar:
    for img_name in img_list:
        # though the chances are very less but be very careful when modifying the below code
        cmd='cwebp \"'+img_name+'\" -q '+quality+' -o \"'+os.path.splitext(img_name)[0]+'.webp\"'
        # running the above command
        call(cmd, shell=False)
        pbar.update(1)

print("Compression completed!\n")
print(f"The compressor converted and compressed {jpg_count} .jpg, {png_count} .png, {jpeg_count} .jpeg, {bmp_count} .bmp, and {tiff_count} .tiff files.")

input("Press Enter to exit...")
```

Answer (score -1):

Another necro but I thought to share an update that worked for me.

First steps stays the same as [DevSolal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21319480/devsolal)'s post, you need `cwebp` and `python`, and;

Second, re [eMad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3578289/emad) and [ann.piv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11384131/ann-piv) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479951/converting-all-images-in-a-folder-to-webp-using-python-script#comment117906735_55479952) for `call(cmd, shell=False)` use `call(cmd, shell=True)`;

So:

```
# --cwebp_compressor.py--

import sys
from subprocess import call
from glob import glob
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
from tqdm import tqdm

# open a prompt to select the folder
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
path = filedialog.askdirectory()

# open a prompt to enter the desired quality
quality = input("Enter the desired quality (0-100): ")

if int(quality) < 0 or int(quality) > 100:
    print("Image quality out of range [0-100] ;/:/")
    sys.exit(0)

img_list = []
jpg_count = 0
png_count = 0
jpeg_count = 0
bmp_count = 0
tiff_count = 0
for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for img_name in filenames:
        # one can use more image types(bmp,tiff,gif)
        if img_name.endswith(".jpg"):
            jpg_count += 1
        elif img_name.endswith(".png"):
            png_count += 1
        elif img_name.endswith(".jpeg"):
            jpeg_count += 1
        elif img_name.endswith(".bmp"):
            bmp_count += 1
        elif img_name.endswith(".tiff") or img_name.endswith(".tif"):
            tiff_count += 1
        else:
            continue
        # extract images name(image_name.[jpg|png]) from the full path
        img_list.append(os.path.join(dirpath, img_name))

with tqdm(total=len(img_list), desc="Compressing Images") as pbar:
    for img_name in img_list:
        # though the chances are very less but be very careful when modifying the below code
        cmd='cwebp \"'+img_name+'\" -q '+quality+' -o \"'+os.path.splitext(img_name)[0]+'.webp\"'
        # running the above command
        call(cmd, shell=True)
        pbar.update(1)

print("Compression completed!\n")
print(f"The compressor converted and compressed {jpg_count} .jpg, {png_count} .png, {jpeg_count} .jpeg, {bmp_count} .bmp, and {tiff_count} .tiff files.")

input("Press Enter to exit...")
```

Then I ran `find . -name "*.tif" -type f -delete` to end up with the same directory structure but WebP instead of TIFF files.

(I would have commented DevSolal's post, but I'm not allowed...)