# Bash "Syntax error: end of file unexpected" when called from Python's (2.7) subprocess.call()

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, unix

I have a `python` (v2.7) script that needs to clear the contents of a file before writing to it (if it exists). I'm able to execute the 'same' command on the command line without issue, but I get a either a `python` or `bash` error when calling variations of this command from `python`. Don't know what I'm missing.

**Ultimate question:** How can I create an empty file (or clear, if it exists) using a system call from Python (v2.7)?

**Bash (successfully creates empty or clears existing file)**

```
$ > test.txt
$ ls -l test.txt
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 <owner> <group> 0 Feb  9 11:26 test.txt
```

**Python (w/o `shell=True'; fails with error)**

I get the following error without using `shell=True`: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. [Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962785/oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-while-using-python-subprocess-in-dj) suggests I shouldn't get this error if I pass all arguments as individual string parameters. Not sure why I get this error.

```
$ python
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['>', 'test.txt']) # Same result w/ single/double quotes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**Python (w/ `shell=True'; fails with error)**

I tried adding `shell=True` per suggestions from the other post (shouldn't be security risk since the command is static), but I get the following `bash` error: `Syntax error: end of file unexpected`. I thought it might need an ending `;` (maybe because of how `python` makes the call?), so I tried two adding a `;` argument with the same end result.

```
$ python
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['>', 'test.txt'], shell=True) # Same result w/ single/double quotes
test.txt: 1: test.txt: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
2
```

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['>', 'test.txt', ';'], shell=True)  # Same result w/ single/double quotes
test.txt: 1: test.txt: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
```

Comment: Does it work when you use an actual command instead of just a redirection, with, say, `subprocess.call([':', '>', 'test.txt'])`?

Comment: Passing a single string would be `.call('> test.txt', shell=True)` but can't you just `open('test.txt', 'w')` and get the same result?

Comment: @Jens: I tried your suggestion (e.g., `subprocess.call(["cat 'hello'", ">", "test.txt"])`, but get the same `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

Comment: @KarlThornton, yes, that does indeed work. I didn't realize that re-opening the file with `python` would accomplish the same objective. I will use this approach, but understanding why my approach doesn't work would still be helpful. I think @MOStudios answered part of it.

Comment: @MarkEbbert No, that's a *different* error. You should not use shell quoting characters when you assemble argument lists. What happens when you run `subprocess.call("echo hello > test.txt")`?

Comment: You seem to be going a very roundabout way to your stated objective.  Depending on the access mode you specify when you open the file, Python will *automically* clear its contents.  Write-only modes based on `'w'` and read/write modes based on `'w+'` will do this (and this is the primary difference between `'w+'` and `'r+'`).  Why do you want to involve `system()`?

Comment: I am of course assuming that you open the file with `open()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `shell=True` Error

When using this, the command given is meant to be formatted as ONE string

The command string given is then interpreted as a raw shell command

The correct usage should be like this:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call('> test.txt', shell=True)
0
>>> 
# There will now be an empty file called
# 'test.txt' in the same directory
```

## `shell=False` Error

The command you are running is meant to be ran **on top** of a shell, but when using this way, it tries to run your string by calling it as a command found in your PATH

However, I don't know how to solve this part of the issue for your case.

Comment: that is helpful. I didn't see that `shell=True` requires a single string. Kind of strange, but submitting as one string worked! **You'll want to update your answer to show the call as one string**. It's presently formatted as multiple arguments like I was doing. The `;` character was also not needed.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry about that, i guess when i formatted it as one string in the answer, it didn't save, i'll change it anyway